# Why BSD queue.h LIST called a list?

Tags: c, list, data-structures, queue, bsd

My "mothertongue" is Java, and I need to write a project in C in educational purposes. I try to understand the `queue.h` library. In Java by default you `add()` an item to the end of the `List`, however in `queue.h`there is only `LIST_INSERT_HEAD` macro that doesn't accept other members. In fact, a small test shows that it inserts to the HEAD (when traversing with `LIST_FOREACH` it goes from the last inserted element to the first). So, doen't this should be called FILO queue (that means a stack)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List in Java corresponds to the [List ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)): "an ordered sequence of values, where the same value may occur more than once".

LIST in queue.h is also a List ADT, in which you can see the implementation details (it is implemented as a doubly linked list). It is LIFO, as the very queue.h file states (though quite murkily). And yes, one way to implement a [Stack ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) is by [using a linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Linked_list).

Answer (score 1):

You should have missed others, INSERT_TAIL must be present. Kindly do a find and confirm that.

It has both the functionalities, list and queue :)

May be the below, is not the one, you are looking, anyway
http://bxr.su/o/queue.h

Comment: There is `TAILQ` macro that does have `INSERT_TAIL`. However there is no such method in List, so it's quite weird to me.

Comment: Yep, Its a design choice, for adding in the tail, you have to use TAILQ, otherwise LIST is fine. Please don't confuse with Java LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of queue options provided by [`queue.h`](http://bxr.su/o/queue.h).

Since this is all done by the pre-processor, and, also note that the full path of the file is [`src/sys/sys/queue.h`](http://OpenBSD.SU/%7BOpenGrok/src/sys/sys/queue.h) on every BSD system, meaning that it's heavily used within the kernel for internal structures, each variant is highly optimised for efficiency and lowest memory footprint.

On OpenBSD, it appears that there are a couple of choices for queues to choose from (each BSD system may have a slightly different selection here):

- http://bxr.su/o/queue.h#SLIST_HEAD
- http://bxr.su/o/queue.h#LIST_HEAD
- http://bxr.su/o/queue.h#SIMPLEQ_HEAD
- http://bxr.su/o/queue.h#XSIMPLEQ_HEAD*
- http://bxr.su/o/queue.h#TAILQ_HEAD
- http://bxr.su/o/queue.h#CIRCLEQ_HEAD*

** For whichever reason, it appears that presently only 4 out of the 6 choices are officially documented in the [manual page](http://mdoc.su/o/queue.3).
See: http://bxr.su/o/share/man/man3/queue.3*

If you want to be able to `INSERT_TAIL` into the queue/list, you still do have a lot of options to choose from here -- `SIMPLEQ`, `XSIMPLEQ`, `TAILQ` and `CIRCLEQ`.

*So, in **summary**: there's no law that says that a queue/list implementation by the name `LIST` has to allow tail insertion!*